# How can we increase the maximum size of a list templates in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010

I have a Picture Library having some pictures in it. Now, I want to move it to some other site. For that I was trying to create a template (with content) for this picture library. But it error-ed out saying

> 'The list is too large to save as a template. The size of a template
>   cannot exceed 52428800 bytes.'.

How can I increase the maximum size of a list templates in SharePoint 2010 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try:

> stsadm -o setproperty -propertyname max-template-document-size
>   -propertyvalue 100000000

That's for 100 MB limit.

Comment: Do we have some option for this via Central Administration.    I hate running commands :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also backup the library and restore it at a different location. See [granular backup and restore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/21/sharepoint-2010-granular-backup-restore-part-1.aspx).

There is also a codeplex tool to help you. [Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/)